# LINQ to SQL and the the order of Take() and Skip()

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am fiddling with LINQ to SQL and LINQ, and I have come across something which I cannot quite understand.

When I do this:

```
var a = Table.Select(s => s.Id).Take(5).Count();
var b = Table.Select(s => s.Id).Take(5).Skip(2).Count();
var c = Table.Select(s => s.Id).Skip(2).Take(5).Count();
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", a, b, c);
```

I get

```
5, 5, 5
```

I would expect to get 5, 3, 5 (as is also the case if I try and simulate with a List)

```
var data = new List<int> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

var a = data.AsQueryable().Select(d=>d).Take(5);
var b = data.AsQueryable().Select(d=>d).Take(5).Skip(2);
var c = data.AsQueryable().Select(d=>d).Skip(2).Take(5);
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", a, b, c);

5, 3, 5
```

What is going on?

Comment: I thought it should be `5,3,5`?

Comment: LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Objects have nothing in common except the syntax. What is the **SQL** statement generated by the Take/Skip calls? Take generally translates to a TOP(n) statement but Skip doesn't have a direct equivalent so it has to execute as Linq to Objects on the results of the query. So Take/Skip is a TOP(5) followed by an in-memory skip, while Skip/Take is all in memory

Comment: I get 5,3,5 from both an array (with 100 elements) and a table (with lots more than 7 elements). Are you *sure* this is what you're getting?

Comment: 5, 3, 5 is what I get in the List example. Changed that in the Q. (Re-wrote the code to be more readable, but reversed `b` and `c`.)

Comment: Are you sure you don't get `5,3,5` for both? That's what I'm getting

Comment: Yes. I get 5, 5, 5 for the former.

Comment: Try testing it in LINQPad, perhaps there's bugs in older versions of Linq2Sql?

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me, a) Takes five elements, b) Takes 5 elements, then skips two of the five elements. c) skips two elements and takes the next 5.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That's incorrect. The Skip is also translated to SQL. No in memory filtering is happening here.

Comment: This is actually the output from LINQpad 4.47.02 with the Albahari MySQL driver.

Comment: @Derek The weird result is the 5,5,5 not the 5,3,5.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth T-SQL has no equivalent to Skip, unless you start using windowing functions. Perhaps L2S uses them, perhaps not. In any case, List is a *VERY* poor simulation for the T-SQL generated by L2S

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You can easily simulate a skip with a sub query. Your previous comment about it being an in memory operation has nothing to do with simulating T-SQL with lists.

Comment: @lejon Are you sure you haven't switched `Take` with  `skip`? , Can you run this query again? And check what is it's equivalent SQL query.I strongly feel there must be some kind of typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you use Albahari MySQL driver. If you look at generated SQL for second query you will find out, that `Skip(2)` invocation is not included there. I have output like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT t1.id
FROM (
    SELECT t2.id
    FROM event AS t2
    LIMIT 0, 5
    ) AS t1
) AS t0
```

Apparently `Skip` works only when followed by `Take`. It may be bug, but it may be by design because of how `LIMIT` clause in MySQL works.

I found a way to past it. For this code:

```
var b = Events.Select(s => s.Id).Take(5).Skip(2).Take(int.MaxValue).Count();
```

you will have:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT t1.id
FROM (
    SELECT t2.id
    FROM event AS t2
    LIMIT 0, 5
    ) AS t1
LIMIT 2, 2147483647
) AS t0
```

Comment: Awesome!How did you get the SQL output from the LINQ query?

Comment: You can preview it in LINQPad or by enabling sql query logging in your app.